# Cannot load Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I am very new to linux. I installed Ubuntu(18.04.4 LTS) alongside my Windows 7(x64). Even though I can boot into Ubuntu without any problems whenever I select Windows 7 from the grub menu the screen is just frozen with a wine color on it. Grub says that my Windows is on sda1 while I have checked that the windows files are on sda3. I have attached the scrshot of fdisk -l command on ubuntu. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPcdk.png)

Comment: Welcome! Did you tried `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Can you manage to boot into your BIOS and boot windows 7 as primary boot?

Comment: FYI:  this looks a lot like https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437800

Comment: Hey I have solved the problem. I tried a bunch of things but I think the answer @guillermochamorro is the one that solved it. Thanks!